# How can I search a listbox items depending on a variable?

Tags: c#, sql, search, listbox

I am new to c# and trying to search a listbox as following :
First i have this :

```cs
 public partial class FrmCodes : Form
 {
        ...
        SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server = AMR-PC\SQLEXPRESS ; Database=PlanningDB ; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader DataRead;
        ...

    public FrmCodes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Item from Items", Cn);
        Cn.Open();
        DataRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (DataRead.Read())
        {
            ListItems.Items.Add(DataRead["Item"].ToString());
        }
        DataRead.Close();
        Cn.Close();
    }
```

And tried to do this :

```cs
private void txtSrch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItems.Items.Clear();
    while (DataRead.Read())
    {
        string str = DataRead["Item"].ToString();
        string srch = txtSrch.Text;
        if (str.Contains(srch))
        {
            ListItems.Items.Add(str);
        }
    }
}
```

It did not work , I tried to make a new sql select query that get data depending on `txtSrch.Text` but got nothing either .
Thanks in advance.

**Edit#1**
This is the query i mentioned before :

```cs
private void txtSrch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItems.Items.Clear();

    SqlConnection Cn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Server = AMR-PC\SQLEXPRESS ; Database=PlanningDB ; Integrated Security = True");
    Cn2.Open();

    string srch = txtSrch.Text;
    using (SqlDataAdapter a2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Item from Items WHERE Item LIKE '%" + srch + "%'", Cn2))
    {
        var t2 = new DataTable();
        a2.Fill(t2);

        ListItems.DisplayMember = "Item";
        ListItems.ValueMember = "Code";
        ListItems.DataSource = t2;
    }
}
```

This did not affect the items in the listbox nothing happens on `txtSrch` Change .

Comment: Could you please update your post to include further details and context. Are you wanting to make a query to return results based on the `txtSrch.Text` and or are you wanting to search the `ListItems` control, it's not clear. Honestly, you should be querying the db for this data, it could change perhaps. Another option is create a `DataView` from your query and bind that to your `ListItems` control. Then you can filter the `DataView` that is bound to your control.

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean? What happened exactly? Did you get a compilation error, a runtime exception (which one?) or did you not get the expected items? Please, elaborate. Also, you did not show us your SQL query approach.

Comment: @Trevor Thanks for reply I want to search the listbox on change of txtSrch, The query i tried to make was to serve the same purpose.

Comment: If this data doesn't change at all really, create a query to return the results and create a `DataView` that you can bind to your `ListItems` `DataSource` property. Then in your `txtSrch_TextChanged` event filter the new `DataView` that is bound to your `ListItems` control. If data changes frequently and would become stale, then you need to hit the DB again and assign this data to the `DataView`...

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks for reply ,  Please have a look on Edit#1 in the question .

Comment: @Trevor Could you make a demo code ?

Comment: Note, you cannot mix adding items with `ListItems.Items.Add(str);` or clearing them with ` ListItems.Items.Clear();` and using a data source with `ListItems.DataSource = t2;`. With a data source clear the items with `ListItems.DataSource = null;` or by assiging it a new empty data source. But you still did not explain what does not work.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks , The second query dd not do anything at all that what i meant by did not work , You mentioned a great point which i did not know before which is  you cannot mix adding items with `ListItems.Items.Add(str);` or clearing them with   ListItems.Items.Clear(); so I Used `Datasource = null ` with the query and it worked fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using `Dataview` thanks to @Trevor

```
public partial class FrmCodes : Form
{
        ...
        SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server = AMR-PC\SQLEXPRESS ; Database=PlanningDB ; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ...

    public FrmCodes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Item from Items", Cn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        ListItems.DataSource = dv;
        ListItems.DisplayMember = "Item";
    }
```

Textbox change :

```
private void txtSrch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ListItems.DataSource = null;
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    string srch = txtSrch.Text;
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Item Like '%{0}%'", srch);
    ListItems.DataSource = dv;
    ListItems.DisplayMember = "Item";
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basedon @Olivier Jacot-Descombes’ comments, this worked for me:

```
private void txtSrch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItems.DataSource = null;

    SqlConnection Cn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Server = AMR-PC\SQLEXPRESS ; Database=PlanningDB ; Integrated Security = True");
    Cn2.Open();

    string srch = txtSrch.Text;
    using (SqlDataAdapter a2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Item from Items WHERE Item LIKE '%" + srch + "%'", Cn2))
    {
        var t2 = new DataTable();
        a2.Fill(t2);

        ListItems.DisplayMember = "Item";
        ListItems.ValueMember = "Code";
        ListItems.DataSource = t2;
    }
}
```